# How to properly set data in component and unit test with Vue?

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, testing, vuejs2, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to unit test a simple method in Vue 2

```
  logNumberInSet (index, inputsLength) {
     this.numberInASet[index] = inputsLength + 1;
  },
```

```
data () {
    return {
      numberInASet: [],
    }
```

I have tried using setData and just an assignment

```
  it("checks how many in set", async () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent);

    wrapper.setData({ numberInASet: [] });
    // wrapper.vm.numberInASet = []; // have also tried this but didn't work
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();

    MyComponent.methods.logNumberInSet(0, 1);
    const number = wrapper.vm.numberInASet[0];

    expect(number).toEqual(1);
  });
```

But when I run the test I get "TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined"

What am I doing wrong, how do you set the data numberInASet properly?

Thanks

Comment: Do you get the same error if you trigger the method through the wrapper e.g. `wrapper.vm.logNumberInSet(0, 1)`?

Comment: Omg thank you, that worked! But I don't understand why, since I thought that would be called the same way

Comment: It's because the wrapper holds the actual instance of the component.

Comment: Ok thank you! Yea I have other tests that use MyComponent.methods.methodName and that worked. Would it be because in this test I did shallowMount that it forces the wrapper to be used instead?